# How to separate the intercept and coefficient from params function in statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, statsmodels

I'm trying to extract only the coefficient from statsmodels using the params function so I can put it into a data frame. When printing `coef_and_intercept` it gives me both the intercept and coefficient.

I tried adding `params.index[1]` which gives me the coef name but it does not display its value.

What could I add to params to only display the coefficient name and its value?

Here is the code.

```
df = pd.read_excel("dataset\Special_Proj.xlsx") 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
tickers = ['FDX', 'BRK', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']

def rolling_reg():

    model = smf.ols('FDX ~ SP50', data=df).fit()
    coef_and_intercept = model.params
    print(coef_and_intercept)
    

rolling_reg()
```

Here is the output of `model.params` (Where I only need SP50)

```
Intercept    10.29
SP50          2.33
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You have to illicit what parameter value you are looking for. Even though it does not display the name, it prints out the coef value.

Just need to add `model.params['SP50']` to get the coef value.

```
def rolling_reg():

    model = smf.ols('FDX ~ SP50', data=df).fit()
    coef_and_intercept = model.params['SP50']
    print(coef_and_intercept)
    

rolling_reg()
```

Comment: A couple steps that can help diagnose something like this in the future, where you don't know what tyoe an object is or how to access it's attributes: `type(coef_and_intercept)` can tell you what it is, `coef_and_intercept?` can give you the help (?) for the object. Knowing, after that, tat it's a pandas series, you can do something like `results.params.to_dict()` to get the key, value pairs